# Polylines showing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have an array of Lat/Lng's that I would like to be able to display on a poly line.

Apologies if this is not very clear, please let me know HOW TO IMPROVE.

Here is an example of the array (Note the third object is the heading):

> "Cot":[-37.582214,172.307343,null,-37.576828,172.321808,65.0,-37.155396,173.440231,65.0,-37.151962,173.45285,70.0,-37.148872,173.465286,70.0,-37.145985,173.477768,75.0,-37.138184,173.520584,75.0,-37.136169,173.532623,80.0,-37.054092,174.024567,80.0,-37.052032,174.03653,75.0,-37.043655,174.084564,75.0,-37.041733,174.096069,80.0,-37.007034,174.300613,80.0,-37.004932,174.312897,75.0,-36.99559,174.366943,75.0,-36.993576,174.378922,80.0,-36.989849,174.400497,80.0,-36.987946,174.411575,75.0,-36.981812,174.445007,75.0]

There are multiple aircraft(markers) on the map, when I use the code below it will read the first lat/lng of the array and if I click on another marker it will draw a line to another marker how ever I would like to be able to have  a poly line behind each marker that shows when the user clicks on the marker and  updates as the marker moves instead of it drawing a line to another marker start point (As seen in images below).

```
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(p.Cot[0] , p.Cot[1]));
      poly.setPath(path);


var polyOptions = {
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  }
  poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
  poly.setMap(Map);

  var path = new google.maps.MVCArray(); 
  // every time the path is updated, automatically the map will update the polyline
```

Images to help explain whats going wrong:
https://ibb.co/n5n2Gc
https://ibb.co/jauShH

Comment: What is your "copy of a jsfiddle" suppose to represent?  It doesn't do anything that I can see.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue **in the question itself**.

Comment: @geocodezip Not sure why it is not working, It is susposed to contain the whole code for the site rather then just snippets on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The "whole code for the site" is not a [mcve].

Comment: @geocodezip Noted and removed, tought it would help as most people do include one.

Comment: It is only useful if it works, is minimal and reproduces the issue (and in any case, the [mcve] should _also_ be present in the question itself).